# How to call p:dialog from JSF Backing bean

Tags: jsf

When I call the `showMessage()` method I get this error:

```
MalformedXML : 'dlg1' is undefined
```

Here is my code:

**addApplicant.xhtml**

```
<p:dialog id="record_error" header="Applicant" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40" >
  <h:outputText value="Applicant already exists" />
</p:dialog>
```

**addApplicantBacking.java:**

```
public void showMessage() {     
  RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
  context.execute("dlg1.show();");
}
```

Comment: If you're using PrimeFaces 5 you need to execute `PF('dlg1').show()`

Comment: A method on the backing-bean that has no other function than executing a javascript call? use `onclick` instead.

Comment: RevanProdigalKnight, your suggestion worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In PrimeFaces 5 you need to execute `PF('dlg1').show()` – ( Thanks RevanProdigalKnight )